# файл html в корне Django

Tags: html, django, url

Есть сайт на Django. Для того чтобы пройти проверку на одном из сервисе надо загрузить html фаил, чтобы открывался по адресу http://saitt.ru/file.html как это сделать?

Если загрузить в директорию  /public/ - то не открывается - Страница не найдена!

Если загрузить в /public/static - то файл откроется через ttp://saitt.ru/static/file.html

Надо что urls.py прописать что-то? В urlpatterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В корневом urls.py (который в вашем корневом приложении) напишите

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^file.html$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='public/file.html')),
]
```

Comment: благодарю, тоже рабочий вариант! Только при таком варианте file.html должен быть в templates. И соответственно ->  url(r'^file.html$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='file.html')),

Answer (score 0):

Решил добавив в конфигурационный файл *nginx.conf*

```
location  /file.html  {
    alias   /ПУТЬ/public/static/file.html ;
}
```